# Imshow not able to update image when using Haar Cascade opencv

Tags: opencv, imshow, haar-classifier

I had used Haar-Cascade to detect human on a thermal image in raspberry Pi. In order to improve the model performance, i had used 2000 of images to train the model. Now the model size is 201kb. Previously it was 60kb and 89kb when i trained the model with less no. of images. As I use 201kb model and detect the human and display it on the screen using IMSHOW, Imshow doesnot update the image in real time, there is so much of delay or even imshow gets hangs. It works fine for 60kb and 89kb model. 
I even tried using opengl to display the image in real time but no help.

What should i do to make the output display similar to real-time using imshow?

Answer (score 0):

Since it runs fine with smaller models, `imshow` is not the bottleneck. It is likely that `detectMultiscale`with the bigger model takes too much time. You can try to either

1. Reduce the number of stages in the model
2. Resize the input frame
3. Adjust `minSize` and `maxSize` of `detectMultiscale`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently i trained my model for 25 stages, will try to reduce that further and check the model accuracy. Input image size is 80x60, which is itself very small. So according to me, resizing the image is not a good option.